# How can I force django to use the lowest model instance?

Tags: python, django, string, inheritance, django-models

Suppose I have my models set up like this:

```
class B(Model):
        ...
        def __str__(self):
                return "B"
class C(B):
        ...
        def __str__(self):
                return "C"
class A(Model):
        b = ForeignKey(B)

        def __str__(self):
                print "A: %s"%(self.b)

a = A(b=C(...))
a.save()
print str(a) # Prints "A: B"
```

Maybe I'm a bit confused how django inheritance works. My intention is to have the program print `"A: C"` at runtime (since `A.b` is an instance of model `C`)

I think I *might* be asking about [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). But that's only if you know what instance of a subclass you want.

As another example of how I'm confused, I'd like to borrow the example from the docs:

```
# Assume Restaurant, Park, and Museum inherit Place
bills = Restaurant.objects.create(name="Bill's Pub", burger="Bill's Burger")
city_prk = Park.objects.create(name='City Park', num_trails=5)
nose = Museum.objects.create(name='Nose Museum', est=1940)

places = Places.objects.all()
```

I'll definitely get a list of 3 objects (of type `Place`) but I have no way of differentiating the types of places. For example, if I want to print out the str value of each place...

```
for place in places:
    print str(place)
```

...python will just execute `Place.__str__()` and not `Restaurant.__str__()` (for the restaurant) or `Park.__str__()` (for the park). This doesn't seem to happen with "normal" python. Python should normally automatically find the lowest-inherited class and execute the overridden function from that (if B overrides a method from A, B's method will be executed).

Are my assumptions correct? Sorry for the long question (and sorry if it's not clear). I'm not exactly sure how to ask what I'm wondering.

Comment: Your surprise is, well, surprising, given that your requirement makes no sense. A isn't related to C, it's related to B, so there's no reason to use C's method.

Comment: Did you mean to use multiple inheritance? e.g. `class A(Model, C)` then calling C's methods?

Comment: What are you even intending the `b` in `print "A: %s"%(b)` to refer to?  There is no name `b` in scope there.

Comment: @ShashankGupta, I edited the question to (hopefully) make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after  doing more research, I've found what I was looking for was the "polymorphic" app, found here: https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that most python objects work that way, but django models do not. You are doing a multi-table inheritance. Which will create a parent table - B, and a child table - C. C would have a primary key named b_ptr_id which is also a foreign key to B.id. Since A contains a foreign key to B, that is what you get. You can reference the child object like this:

```
b_object = B.objects.get(…)
c_object = b_object.c
```

But of course if multiple tables inherited from B, you would not no which child object to extract. This utility might help you: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager it will do just what you need. Calling `.select_subclasses()` on a query set will automatically "cast" each object to whatever child object it "really" is.